# Makefile - $< for multiple rules

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

According to the gnu make documentation `$<` refers to the first prerequisite:

> $<
> The name of the first prerequisite. If the target got its recipe from an implicit rule, this will be the first prerequisite added by the implicit rule (see Implicit Rules).

But, if I have the following:

```
a: b
a: c
    @echo first prerequisite is: $<
```

This will print `first prerequisite is c`.  While this makes sense, (as it would raise to many sharp sticks if `b` was considered the first prerequisite), I'm not seeing any documentation to support this, I'm wondering if I can rely on this being consistent among other make systems (The POSIX standard also does not seem to expand on this)

Comment: So your question is, "Given this proven outcome, which already makes perfect sense and meets my needs completely, can I get additional validation by seeing a definitive written reference that proves it works under all possible conditions?"  Seldom do I get that level of confidence with anything I write.  I rely on testing and best judgement to make that determination.

Comment: The question, whether using some behavior is portable or not, is perfectly valid. The fact that answering the question requires more than reading the docs doesn't make the question "opinion-based". Voted for reopen.

Comment: Agreed.  This close is really unjustifiable.  There's nothing "opinion based" about asking whether some behavior is guaranteed or is a random side-effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

POSIX doesn't require that `$<` is available at all in explicit rules and there are versions of make that don't make it available.  So using this is not portable in the first place.

From POSIX:

> *In an inference rule*, the $< macro shall evaluate to the filename whose existence allowed the inference rule to be chosen for the target ... The meaning of the $< macro shall be otherwise unspecified.

Emphasis added.  "Inference rule" is the same thing as GNU make's implicit rules (technically it's just suffix rules since POSIX doesn't define pattern rules).

As far as GNU make goes, `$<` is always the first prerequisite *in the rule* (by which I mean, the rule that contains the recipe).  This is definitely guaranteed and I think there should be text alluding to that in the GNU make manual, but I didn't go look.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation.   I did not find any text alluding to this in the GNU make manual.

Comment: I sent a suggestion for an edit to gnu.org for this.